# Is it necessary to be able to do SSH from one node to another in order to do cloudera cluster installation?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am creating a cloudera cluster and when I do SSH from one node to another I get message saying "Public Key".Login to the machines happen using PEM file and paraphrase Is it necessary to be able to do SSH from one node to another in order to do cloudera cluster installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudera Manager requires an SSH key to communicate with the Cloudera SCM Agents and do the installation.

Cloudera Manager installs the cluster for you. but you will need to initially add the `authorized_keys` SSH file for the remote manager to access the agent machines.

[How does Cloudera Manager Work?](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/07/how-does-cloudera-manager-work/) (doesn't mention SSH, though)

Comment: thanks. I am able to do SSH after converting Putty key to OpenSSH key and storing this on each server in id_rsa file . However my cloudera manager installation still fails with message "Exhausted available authentication methods" on giving this OpenSSH key file and the pass phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is necessary. Cloudera manager need a way to access other machines over SSH. This can be authenticated using public keys (recommended) or passwords.